# How do I know whether I am registered in the worldwide registry of French citizens established outside France?

Tags: usa, passport, french-citizens, thailand, us-residents

I am a French citizen, permanent resident in the United States and currently in Thailand, where I'd like to renew my passport because [some airlines require it to be in pristine condition](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155092/1810).

I read on https://th.ambafrance.org/Passeport-d-un-majeur-renouvellement-en-cas-de-pages-epuisees-modification-etat:

> Les personnes inscrites au registre mondial des Français établis hors de France n’ont pas besoin de fournir de justificatif de domicile, sauf si leur adresse a changé.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=Les%20personnes%20inscrites%20au%20registre%20mondial%20des%20Fran%C3%A7ais%20%C3%A9tablis%20hors%20de%20France%20n%E2%80%99ont%20pas%20besoin%20de%20fournir%20de%20justificatif%20de%20domicile%2C%20sauf%20si%20leur%20adresse%20a%20chang%C3%A9.)

> Persons registered in the worldwide registry of French citizens established outside France do not need to provide proof of address, unless their address has changed.

How do I know whether I am registered in the worldwide registry of French citizens established outside France?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any easy way to look that up online. All online forms require you to specify where you are registered and provide your consular registration number (NUMIC). If you don't have one, you have to contact the consulate where you might be registered to recover it. But if you never got one, you probably never registered.

If you decide to register to vote and provide an email address, you will also get quite a bit of email and even some mail from political parties and your MP (who have the right to peruse the electoral register). If you never got any, it would suggest that you never registered (although you can also chose to register at the consulate but not on the electoral register so it's not a definite proof).